# TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "some_url/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        data.forEach(function(element){
            console.log(element);
        });
    }
});
```

I get the error that for each does not work on the `data` variable. However, when I log `data` to the console, I get

`[{"model": "app.mdl", "pk": 1, "fields": {"name": "test", "rank": 1}}]`

This is clearly an array and iterable, so I don't get what exactly is wrong.

EDIT: `data` is returned via `JsonResponse` in Django.

Comment: But there's only one element in the array

Comment: It's just a sample I'm using to check my function before populating my tables with the actual dataset.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I believe *data* is a JSON string. Since `forEach()` is a array function and you are trying to implement it on the JSON string it throws the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function"

You have to parse the data with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) before using `forEach()`:

> The `JSON.parse()` method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string. An optional reviver function can be provided to perform a transformation on the resulting object before it is returned.

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

**Demo:**

```js
var data = JSON.stringify([{"model": "app.mdl", "pk": 1, "fields": {"name": "test", "rank": 1}}]);
data = JSON.parse(data);
data.forEach(function(element){
    console.log(element);
});
```

So the *success* should be:

```
success: function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
    data.forEach(function(element){
        console.log(element);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just check for either it is string or JSOn array

```
if(typeof(data) === "string"){data = JSON.parse(data)}
 data.forEach(function(element){
            console.log(element);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the data is JSON string.

```
data = "[{"model":"app.mdl","pk":1,"fields":{"name":"test","rank":1}}]"
```

if yes, the you have to do JSON.parse(data) and do forEach on it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a case where your `data` response looks like an array but it is a string. If you have access to the API you're connecting to you can ensure the response it sends out is an array but if not simply parsing the `data` response using `JSON.parse()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Change your success function to this, the `JSON.parse()` function is required to iterate over the JSON string:

```
success: function(data){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        data.forEach(function(element){
            console.log(element);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "some_url/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        data.data.forEach(function(element){
            console.log(element);
        });
    }
});

// Just add - data.data.foreach.
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `data` returned from your AJAX request might not be in the expected format. `Object.values(data)` is used to retrieve the values of an object, but if `data` is an array, it won't work as intended.

If your intention is to iterate over each element of the array, you can directly use `data.forEach()` without converting it to an object. Here's a revised version of your code:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "some_url/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        data.forEach(function(element){
            console.log(element);
        });
    }
});
```

This code assumes that `data` is an array. If `data` is indeed an object and you want to iterate over its values, then you can use `Object.values(data)` as you initially suggested. However, ensure that `data` is indeed an object before using `Object.values()`.