# array.forEach is not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm showing array of objects that is received from api call.I'm using react hooks.when I tried to iterate  through array of objects it return foreach is not a function.
for this can I use await and async.

```
function searchArticle() {

    const [articleList, setArticleList] = useState([]); 
    const { articleApiStatus, articleCurrentPage, searcArticle } = state;
    useEffect(() => {
        setArticleList(state.articleList);
        articleListApiCall(articleCurrentPage);
    }, [])

    const articleListApiCall = (page = 1) => {
        const isNewPage = articleCurrentPage !== page;
        if (!articleApiStatus || isNewPage) {
            getArticleList(page, '')
        }
    }
    const getArticleList = async (page, searchkey) => {
         const requestBody = {
            page: page - 1, searchkey
        }
        await onArticleSearchPost(requestBody).then(articleresult => {
            setArticleList(articleresult);          
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }   
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="article-section">
              <div className="search-result">
                <Collapse  >
                {
                        articleList.forEach(element => {
                        <Panel header={element.article_title} key={element._id}>
                          <p>{element.article_body}</p>
                        </Panel>
                        })
                }
              </div>
              <div className="pagination-section">
                  <Pagination defaultCurrent={1} total={50} />
              </div>
            </div>                
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
export default searchArticle;
```

Edit : I'm receiving following data from api call

```
[ 
   {       
      "_id":"5d9efbc3b29b2876700adf6f",
      "postedBy":"Admin",
      "datePosted":"1570700227888",      
      "__v":0
   }   
]
```

Comment: You should wait i.e check if articleList is not empty like: articleList && articleList.forEach(element => {
                        <Panel header={element.article_title} key={element._id}>
                          <p>{element.article_body}</p>
                        </Panel>
                        })

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53275405/typeerror-data-foreach-is-not-a-function
check this like ,its similar to your issue

Answer (score 7):

First of all, do not use `forEach` to render JSX, it won't work. Use `map` instead:

```
<Collapse>
  {articleList.map(element => { // use map
    return (
      <Panel header={element.article_title} key={element._id}>
        <p>{element.article_body}</p>
      </Panel>
    );
  })}
</Collapse>
```

Second, make sure that `state.articleList`, which you're setting to state in `useEffect`, is an actual array.

Comment: My bet is `state.articleList` is not an Array too.

Comment: Its returning object

Comment: @Karthi `map` and  `forEach` are array methods, they won't run on an object. You can try converting it to array first, extracting the array property or using smth like `Object.keys()` to iterate it.

Comment: I need to know the structure of the object you get.

Comment: @Karthi that's an array, not an object, the map should work on it.

Comment: but why it return map is not a function.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more code, like what's the `state` variable and why are you setting it in `useEffect`?

Comment: still don't see `state` anywhere in the component code.

Comment: @Clarity okay I missed articleCurrentPage state variable

Comment: Is that because of late response from api call .

Comment: @Karthi your code is still incomplete. I recommend you to make a minimal _running_ example on codesandbox.