# Using forEach in Javascript with a django json response

Tags: javascript, json, django

**<><><><><>EDIT<><><><><>**

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53275405/typeerror-data-foreach-is-not-a-function). I need to parse the data using JSON.parse() before going into forEach

**<><><><><><><><><><><><>**

I have a json response from django and I'm trying to display each item in the json response as its own div using javascript.

The json response is as follows:

```
[{"model": "network.posts", "pk": 1, "fields": {"user": 1, "post": "hi", "timestamp": "2020-11-10T21:24:51.118Z"}}, {"model": "network.posts", "pk": 2, "fields": {"user": 1, "post": "My first post!", "timestamp": "2020-11-10T21:25:07.893Z"}}, {"model": "network.posts", "pk": 3, "fields": {"user": 2, "post": "This is my 3rd post :)", "timestamp": "2020-11-10T22:43:23.383Z"}}, {"model": "network.posts", "pk": 4, "fields": {"user": 2, "post": "This is my 3rd post :)", "timestamp": "2020-11-10T22:44:34.421Z"}}, {"model": "network.posts", "pk": 5, "fields": {"user": 2, "post": "This is my 3rd post :)", "timestamp": "2020-11-10T22:47:17.896Z"}}]
```

That comes from a django view which is:

```
def get_posts (request):

    # Get list of posts
    posts = Posts.objects.all()

    if request.method == "GET":
        return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', posts), safe=False)
```

For now I'm just trying to console log each 'post' using javascript. Here's what I have so far:

```
// Load all posts

fetch(`/posts`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);

});
```

That works, but it logs the whole json response. What I want to do is chop it up so each post is logged separately, but I can't work it out! I tried using ForEach like this:

```
// Load all posts

fetch(`/posts`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);

  data.forEach( () => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

But I keep getting an error of `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.ForEach is not a function`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Not sure it this is a typo, but it should be `data.forEach` (note different capitalization).

Comment: Also it doesn't make sense to console log the thing you are iterating over.  You log the iteration value

Comment: Thanks I updated it above for the typo. Doesn't quite seem to solve the problem though (still have the same error of "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function")

Answer (score 0):

Like Kryten said in comments, you have a typo. So I think .forEach should work.

```js
data.forEach((el) => {
    console.log(el);
    // or
    console.log(el.model);
    console.log(el.fields);
    ...
});
```

You can also do:

```
for (const el of data) {
    console.log(el.fields);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Using forEach (rather than ForEach, oops!) still returns the same error - even if I do it exactly as your extract above. I also tried your second option (the for loop) but it logs 'undefined' 647 times - I haven't counted but I think it's logging each individual char in the json.