# Javascript Export JSON objects to Excel File

Tags: javascript, html

I'm Trying to Export this JSON table as an Excel file using Javascript so this is what I have tried and I get this error on the Console log

this is prepear.php file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <title>Document</title>
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.16.2/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
        <script src='https://unpkg.com/tesseract.js@v2.1.0/dist/tesseract.min.js'></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <!-- <script src='excelexportjs.js'></script> -->
        <script src='main.js'></script>
        <script src="filesaver.js"></script>
        
        <div class="container mt-5 ">
            <pre id="json"></pre>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="downloadAsExcel(json.innerHTML)">download excel</button>
        </div>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the second file is main.js

```js
async function readFile(fileName)
{
    console.log({
        fileName
    }); 
        
    return await Tesseract.recognize(fileName, 'ara', {
        logger: m => console.log(m)
    }); // fake it ...
}

async function parseDataFromTextAndPropertyNames(text, propertyNames)
{
    console.log({
        text, propertyNames
    });
        
    return propertyNames .reduce((table, key) => Object.assign(table, {
        [ key ]: RegExp(`${ key }\\W+(\\w+)`) .exec(text)?.[1] ?? '' }
    ), {});
}

async function writeParsedTextDataAsJSON(fileName, table)
{
    console.log({
        table
    });
        
    JSON.stringify({
        table
    }) // fake it ...
        
    return (await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        console.log({ fileName, json: JSON.stringify({ table }) });
        resolve({ success: true });
    }, 1500) ));
```

and finally, [filesaver.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jayanthbabu123/export-as-excel-file-from-json-object-by-using-javascript/master/filesaver.js)

The Console Log

> Uncaught TypeError: r.forEach is not a function at rb (xlsx.full.min.js:23:18346) at Object.tb [as json_to_sheet] (xlsx.full.min.js:23:19000) at downloadAsExcel (mains.js:61:32) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (prepare.php:16:83)

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53275463/6381711) useful?

Comment: @nyedidikeke I didn't find something